# Android how can I set an Intent to open adobe connect app

Tags: android, adobe, adobe-connect

I want to check to exist adobe Connect and an intent to open adobe Connect android app

after that, I want to send a URL of a class by this intent

[image]

Comment: you can do it using "package name" of your adobe contact app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution to open adobe connect and set the URL of my class.

```
if (isAppAvailable("air.com.adobe.connectpro")){
    openAdobeClass("connectpro://vc.mohsen.com/nf3")
}

private fun isAppAvailable(packageName: String): Boolean {
    val pm = getPackageManager()
    return try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)
        true
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        false
    }

}

private fun openAdobeClass(url: String) {
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
        data = Uri.parse(url)
        startActivity(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check my updated code. This works nicely

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        Intent sendIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("air.com.adobe.connectpro");
        if (sendIntent != null) {
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "app not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: I installed adobe connect but ``resolveActivity`` always return ``null``

Comment: what is the package name of adobe contact app ?

Comment: air.com.adobe.connectpro

Comment: I changed it but again return null

Comment: @mohsen check my updated code for you I also tested it ;)